# Comparing data with database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to compare the data in my database when user click on to buy   something and the data will compare to database. If the user have this disease, it will not allow user to buy. Anyone can check my code whether got any wrong?

[image: Firebase]

```
 private void submit(){
   myRef.child("Users").child(userID).child("medical");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (postSnapshot.child("medical").getValue(String.class) .equals("Diabetes") ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Diabetes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Medicine.class));
                }else{

                }
            }
        }
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                    at
>   com.bleach.finalyearproject.Pain_and_Fever$1.onDataChange(Pain_and_Fever.java:61

**This the page for user key in their information and store in database**

```
 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Submit pressed.");
            String name = mName.getText().toString();
            String address = mAddress.getText().toString();
            String phoneNum = mPhoneNum.getText().toString();
            String gender = mGender.getText().toString();
            String country = mCountry.getText().toString();
            String medicine = mMedicine.getText().toString();
            String medical = rb.getText().toString();

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Attempting to submit to database: \n" +
                    "name: " + name + "\n" +
                    "address: " + address + "\n" +
                    "phone number: " + phoneNum + "\n" +
                    "gender: " + gender + "\n" +
                    "country: " + country + "\n" +
                    "medicine: " + medicine + "\n" +
                     "medical:" + medical + "\n"
            );

            //handle the exception if the EditText fields are null

           if(!name.equals("") && !address.equals("") && !phoneNum.equals("") && !gender.equals("") && !country.equals("") && !medicine.equals("")){
                UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(name,address,phoneNum,gender,country,medicine,medical);
                myRef.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(userInformation);
                toastMessage("Information has been saved.");
                mName.setText("");
                mAddress.setText("");
                mPhoneNum.setText("");
                mGender.setText("");
                mCountry.setText("");
                mMedicine.setText("");
                rb.setText("");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));


            }else{
                toastMessage("Fill out all the fields");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddToDatabase.class));
            }


        }

    });


        }


public void rbclick(View view){

   int radiobuttonid = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   rb  = (RadioButton) findViewById(radiobuttonid);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),rb.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


 }
```

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: how to solve the problem??

Comment: Please share your database structure.

Comment: my database image at  Firebase<< this word

Comment: Sorry but i cannot see it. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: already add @ in front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query to just load the data for the user if they have Diabetes:

```
myRef.child("Users").child(userID)
     .orderByChild("medical").equalTo("Diabetes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Diabetes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Medicine.class));
        }
    }
```

Or you can just load the user and do the check in the client-side code:

```
myRef.child("Users").child(userID)
     .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.child("medical").getValue(String.class).equals("Diabetes")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Diabetes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Medicine.class));
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have try this 2 ways but still get the same error

Comment: Oops, my code was still dereferencing the non-existing `.child("medical")` on the reference. I removed it now. Please try again.

Comment: the error still the same.. Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found will this error make the thing can't run?

Comment: That sounds like a different error from the `NullPointerException ` you reported originally.